# Is it possible to rewrite a NOT IN query to use indexes?

Tags: sql, sqlite

[Sqlite does not support the use of indexes in queries based around a NOT IN clause](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

Is it possible to logically rewrite a query like the following in such a way that it will only use the operators listed at the link above?

The query:

```
Select *
From table
Where table-column not in (
    Select table-column
    From table2);
```

The operators listed as being able to use an index:

- column = expression
- column > expression
- column >= expression
- column < expression
- column <= expression
- expression = column
- expression > column
- expression >= column
- expression < column
- expression <= column
- column IN (expression-list)
- column IN
  (subquery)
- column IS NULL

Comment: Somehow I would try to make that an IN,but it needs more context.

Comment: Use `NOT EXISTS (...)` , if sqlite supports them. In most cases, _NOT EXISTS_ has better semantics wrt NULLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select A.*
From table a
left join table2 b 
 on a.table-column = b.table-column
WHERE b.table-column is null
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [LEFT JOIN as described in section 6](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

SQLFiddle with sample data [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0cc76/1). Expand *View Execution Plan* to confirm that the original query does a table scan, while the LEFT JOIN query uses the index.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   Table1

   LEFT JOIN Table2
   ON Table1.table-column = Table2.table_column
WHERE
   Table2.table_column IS NULL
```